# Show DIV X, if Div Y contains Z. Then, show Div A, if Div Y contains B

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I've got some code I've been working on, effectively to hash together a progress step bar.

The HTML:

```
<div id="stage1"><img src="/img/progress-bar/1.png"></div>
<div id="stage2"><img src="/img/progress-bar/2.png"></div>
<div class="deal-stage">2</div>
```

Now I want to display the DIV #stage1 if the div .deal-stage contains the number 1. I then want to display the DIV #stage2 if the div .deal-stage contains the number 2.

All HTML looks ok, it's the JQuery that's troubling me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
if($('.deal-stage').html() == 1){
$("#stage1").show();
if($('.deal-stage').html() == 2){
$("#stage2").show();
}
});//]]> 
</script>
```

At the moment both DIVs are showing. I want to add 4 more steps but I'm not sure how to only display one of the DIVS at a time by looking up the number in the .deal-stage DIV.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide your images before the page loads like so :

```
<div id="stage1" style="display:none;"><img src="/img/progress-bar/1.png"></div>
<div id="stage2" style="display:none;"><img src="/img/progress-bar/2.png"></div>
<div class="deal-stage">2</div>
```

Then change your script slightly to make it a little more compliant :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if($('.deal-stage').html() == "1"){
    $("#stage1").show();
}
if($('.deal-stage').html() == "2"){
    $("#stage2").show();
}
});
```

And you'll be good to go.

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly, I was close, but you got me there. The difference between an amateur and a pro!